# twitteR in R can't detect/specify the geocode

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining

I intended to get a twitter data related to 'education' (using keyword #education as my hashtag). Yet, I want to retrieve data about it by specific geo-location too (e.g London, Tokyo).

So, I type this code on R:

```
A <- twListToDF(searchTwitter('#education', n = 10000, geocode("London",   
            source = "dsk"), lang = 'en', since = '2018-09-1',until = 
            "2018-9-30"))
B <- twListToDF(searchTwitter('#education', n = 10000, geocode("Tokyo", 
            source = "dsk"), lang = 'en', since = '2018-09-1',until = 
            "2018-9-30"))
```

But, I'm getting the result like this (in every code):

Warning message: In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params,
  retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  : 10000 tweets were requested
  but the API can only return 2785

P.s: longitude, latitude were NA and all the tweets from A & B were the same.
     it seem twiter doesn't differ its location.

How can I resolve this? Please guide me...

Comment: You haven't named the `geocode` argument, are you sure it's being matched up correctly? You may want to try `searchTwitter('#education', n = 10000, geocode = geocode("London", source = "dsk"), <etc>)`

Comment: @Marius well thx for commenting, but its create new error result: Error in strsplit(geocode[[1]], ",") : non-character argument. Sorry I'm new to this...

Comment: You should check out https://rtweet.info/ it's preferable these days as the latest twitteR version is 2 years old. twitteR can't even handle tweets longer than 140 characters which disqualifies it for me (that wasn't a problem when the package was last updated obviously).

Comment: @JBGruber Oh I see, okay thankyou!